# Unable to Remote Login a Ubuntu Router via OpenSSH with Successful Ping Result

Tags: ssh, login, iptables

I want to remotely login a Ubuntu Router via OpenSSH but when I type the following to login, I cannot get back any response from the Ubuntu Router in the command line.

```
ssh casper@192.168.1.1
```

- Login the Ubuntu Router via SSH from a host behind the Ubuntu Router ⇒ **Fail**
- Login the Ubuntu Router via SSH from a host outside the router private network `192.168.1.0` ⇒ **Fail**

---

#### IPs of the Ubuntu Router

```
# External
IP Address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

# Internal
IP Address: 192.168.1.1
```

---

#### Testing

Then, I tried the followings to test.

- Login the Ubuntu Router via SSH in the Ubuntu Router itself ⇒ **Success**
- Ping `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` from a host behind the Ubuntu Router ⇒ **Success**
- Ping `192.168.1.1` from a host behind the Ubuntu Router ⇒ **Success**
- Ping `8.8.8.8` from a host behind the Ubuntu Router ⇒ **Success**
- Ping `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` from a host outside the router private network `192.168.1.0` ⇒ **Success**

Therefore, I concluded that the package can reach the Ubuntu Router but it cannot trigger the SSH response for requesting password for login. After tried the following command to unblock port 22 by the iptables (1), the problem still not solved.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

---

#### Question

How to successfully login the Ubuntu Router via SSH?

---

#### Reference

1. IPTables rule to allow incoming SSH connections
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136204/48296

Comment: Do you live in or around Beijing, where the unlikely IP address `123.123.123.123` is registered?  If not, it is probably not your external IP address.  I have used some models of HP access point which return that IP address for some DNS errors, instead of an appropriate error code.

Comment: Adding a link to show that I am not the only one to observe this problem with HP access points: http://community.hpe.com/t5/MSM-Series/Access-Controller-VSC-DNS-reply-123-123-123-123/td-p/5796025

Comment: Sorry, this address is just an assumption.

Comment: no problem, just wanted to check on that, as I have seen that "feature" cause difficult to diagnose problems.  Should have considered the rest of the question instead of getting stuck at the IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no iptables rule allowing *incoming* ssh connections:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

The line you quote above will allow `sshd` to respond to incoming ssh connections (if the responses were otherwise blocked), but will not allow remote clients to establish a connection.

Comment: I have tested this answer and it works!!